# AutoCompleteTextView popuptheme being ignored

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have this AutoCompleteTextView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/search_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/half_spacing"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_spacing"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_search_autocomplete"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/single_spacing"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"

                    android:hint="@string/dashboard_city_search_hint"
                    android:padding="@dimen/single_spacing"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/half_spacing"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/half_spacing">

            </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView>
```

I want the EditText to be AppTheme.Dark and the popup Apptheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">

(...)
</style>

 <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
(...)
</style>
```

However the popup is still Dark themed. If I change theme to the entire AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView the popup shows up as white.

Comment: does it work if you use just for testing `AutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes, Resources.Theme popupTheme)` constructor?

Comment: well incidentaly you hit the nail cause turns out AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView does not have that constructor. However using AutoCompleteTextView, while it responds to popupTheme, shows the background as white with also white text

Comment: yes, indeed i missed you are using `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView` not `ACTV` but maybe because you used `ACTV` in the title

Comment: Also it seems this constructor is only available from SDK 24 on... so this is not good for me anyway :(

Comment: ok and why do you want to use this theme? just aesthetic reasons? or to fix something?

Comment: aesthetic reasons, the black menu looks terrible in my app, but at the same time the edittext needs to be dark-themed. I had to resort to manually changing the stuff